# Problems importing request and session from flask

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, import

VS Code is not recognizing import requests and session from flask. When I write the code it initializes request and session as variables.

I have pip uninstalled and reinstalled `flask 2.1`. I’m using VS Code for IDE and running MacBook Pro M1. Why do I have this problem?

[image: Picture of the code]

Comment: Show error and the code you're using

Comment: Added a picture of the code. I'm new to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

In the Integrated Terminal, run the app by entering , which runs the Flask development server. The development server looks for by default. When you run Flask, you should see output similar to the following:`python -m flask runapp.py`

To open your default browser to the rendered page, Ctrl+click the URL in the terminal.`http://127.0.0.1:5000/`

You can refer to the [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask) of flask in vscode for more details